# How to compare each and every element of first array and each and every element of second array

Tags: java, algorithm

How do I compare the nth element of the first array with nth element of the second array?

- Suppose the first element of the first array is greater than the first element of the second array
- compare the second element of the two array
- if both the element are greater than the second array print `WIN`
- if one of the element of the first array is smaller than the second array print `LOSE`

If all the element of the first array is greater than all the element of the second array print `WIN` else print `LOSE`

Example 1:

```
6
10 20 50 100 500 400 
30 20 60 70 90 490 
LOSE
```

Example 2:

```
5
10 20 30 40 50 
40 50 60 70 80
WIN
```

explanation:

in first input array size is 6
since array2 index 3 is less than array1 index 3 so it print lose
but in second input all the element in array2 is greater than element of array1 so it print win

[i have tried this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WBhAJ.png)

```
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int i,j;
        int n=sc.nextInt();
        int a[]=new int[n];
        int b[]=new int[n];
        for(i=0;i<n;i++)
            a[i]=sc.nextInt();
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
            b[j]=sc.nextInt();
        for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
            for(j=0;j<b.length;j++){
                if(b[j]>a[i]){
                    System.out.println("WIN");
                }else
                System.out.println("LOSE");
            }           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does the arrangement of array elements matters?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please check [How do I ask homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). In this case, you need to show what you have done. We're volunteers and are willing to help you to **fix** your code, but we won't do your homework for you. So, you need to read [ask] and post your code as a [mcve] that we can copy-paste and see the specific part you're stuck. Show the desired and actual input & output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of, you actually only need one loop. Since both arrays have the same size you can compare them without the need of a second loop:

```
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ 
 if(b[i] > a[i])
  ...
}
```

Since your code probably prints "WIN" for every index that has a higher value, there may be a decent workaround. What you can do, is set a variable at the beginning of your code and only change it, when a specific requirement is met. And then you can just insert a print as the last line with said variable:

```
String result = "WIN";
...
for(int i=0; i<n; i++){ 
 if(b[i] < a[i])
  result = "LOSE";
}
System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: But if you've already lost, why not just skip the rest of the computations? i.e. `break` the loops

Comment: You could and probably should do that. I just meant to present the idea and did not go too much into optimization. Also the person asking the question seems to be at the beginning of his programming career, so I kept it simple.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take a different approach, your condition is:

> Print WIN if all numbers in second array are greater than the ones in each index of first array, otherwise print LOSE

What you're doing right now is: Asking for ALL the greater numbers, ask the other way, when you find a number that is lower than the one in the first array, you lose. So:

1. Create a flag variable, let's call it `win`

   ```
   boolean win = true;
   ```
2. Change your condition

   From:

   ```
   if(b[j] > a[i]) {
   ```

   To:

   ```
   if(b[j] < a[i]) {
   ```
3. Inside that condition change your flag to `false`, this means there's at least one value in the second array lower than the one in the first one. And break the loops

   ```
   win = false;
   break;
   ```
4. Then just ask for the value in `win`:

   ```
   if (win) {
       System.out.println("WIN");
   } else {
       System.out.println("LOSE");
   }
   ```

You're done!

---

Your code should end up as something like this (I improved the spacing for readability and you should do so as well, and I also added curly braces to the loops for readability)

```
import java.util.*;
public class CandidateCode {
    public static void main(String args[] ) throws Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i, j;
        int n = sc.nextInt();
        int a[] = new int[n];
        int b[] = new int[n];
        boolean win = true;
        for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            b[j]=sc.nextInt();
        }
        for(i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for(j = 0; j < b.length; j++) {
                if(b[j] < a[i]) {
                    win = false;
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }
        if (win) {
            System.out.println("WIN");
        } else {
            System.out.println("LOSE");
        }
    }
}
```

Example outputs:

```
3
1 2 3
4 5 6
WIN

3
1 4 5
2 1 6
LOSE
```

Comment: You're welcome. When you ask questions here, be sure to include the code in the question (not as pictures), to explain correctly what you need and to include input/output examples. All of these will make your questions better and will have faster and better answers.